# Does "level" in exponential smoothing stand for the "mean"?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

In triple exponential smoothing it is said that there are estimates for 3 components: level, trend and seasonal. Does "level" here stand for "mean"?
In single exponential smoothing is only the level component and is estimated as a flat line which seems to be the mean (as per the image below, the dashed horizontal line)

[image: Single exponential smoothing - forecast for level only]

Comment: Just co-incidence in that plot  - see [Hyndman & Athanasopoulos, *Forecasting: principles & practice*, Ch. 7.1](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/1).

Comment: ok, so if i understand correctly, if i would give a definition for "level" it would be the forecast of the time series ignoring trend or seasonality. is this correct?

Comment: still no answer?!?

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'level' means a weighted average between the prediction and real value. If we are taking a simple exponential-smoothing method without trend, we will get:

$$\hat y_{T+1\mid T}=\alpha y_T+(1-\alpha) \hat y_{T\mid T-1}.$$

To get a $(T+1)$ step prediction, you take a weighted average of the $T $ step real value and $T$ step prediction. So in the exponential-smoothing with trend, you should also take a weighted average of them to get a "level", and then add the trend to get a final prediction.